# selecting a specific item in JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON object that when I do this:

```
console.log(response.json);
```

I get this

```
{ results:
   [ { address_components: [Object],
       formatted_address: 'Google Bldg 42, 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA',
       geometry: [Object],
       place_id: 'ChIJPzxqWQK6j4AR3OFRJ6LMaKo',
       types: [Object] } ],
  status: 'OK' }
```

I want to be able to select `formated_address` as an example. I've tried variations of `console.log(response.json.formatted_address);` that but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an object inside an array, so you need to specify the first item in the array.

```
response.json.results[0].formatted_address
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just access the first element , i.e index **`0`** of the **`array`** and then **`formatted_address`**

```
console.log(response.json.result[0].formatted_address);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is not accessible directly so you need to do something like this.Your formatted_address lies in an array which is present in the result key.So to get your result do something like this

```
console.log(response.json.result[0].formatted_address);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
console.log(response.json.results[0].formatted_address);
```